# DynamoDB how to use index in PartiQL queries?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, partiql

I have seen the dynamoDB doc for the PartiQL syntax:

```
SELECT expression  [, ...] 
FROM table[.index]
[ WHERE condition ] [ [ORDER BY key  [DESC|ASC] , ...]
```

but in practice:

```
select * from dev .pk-all-index
where "pk" = 'config' AND ("brand" = 'tesla' OR contains("aliases", 'tesla.com'))
```

gives me the error:

> An error occurred during the execution of the command.
> ValidationException: Statement wasn't well formed, can't be processed:
> Unexpected keyword

Comment: Try `from dev.pk-all-index` (so: no space after `dev`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it doesn't work without "

Comment: Did you mean that you need to use `"dev"."pk-all-index"`? That might be the result of the `-` in the identifier, and maybe your schema is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
from "tablename"."indexname"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: hmmm i feel like this is straightforward enough?

Comment: Is it? What does your answer tell the OP? It does not contain a valid SQL statement, it does not contain the table names used in his own query, it does not tell him what he did wrong

Comment: This syntax is documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.Indexes.QueryAndScan.html

Answer (score 6):

You might want to put the table name and index under quotes, individually.

```
SELECT * FROM "dev"."pk-all-index" WHERE "pk" = 'config' AND ("brand" = 'tesla' OR contains("aliases", 'tesla.com'))
```